# Having problem with borders on segmented button using tailwind

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Trying to create segmented button, but having problem with borders.
I want to have 1px border everywhere including between buttons

Structure for 2nd variant (buttons are rendered dynamically)

```
<div class="divide-x">
 <button class="border-y first:border-l last:border-r">
</div>
```

I have tried multiple ways of borders

- 1st borders on each button but than I have 2px between buttons, and with tailwind I can specify only first/last button to remove border between buttons (I dont want to install aditional libraries)
- 2nd divide-x on parent + border-y + on child(button) first:border-r and last:border-r for some reason last:border-r doesnt apply and creates something like this

any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your post and add css code please ? :)

Comment: added tailwind classes to my structure example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Mnx69F64VP)?

```html
<div class="divide-x divide-black border border-black rounded-full">
    <button class="py-2 px-8">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8">hello</button>
</div>
```

or like [this](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mo4F7lUfad)?

```html
<div class="flex">
    <button class="py-2 px-8 border-y border-l first:rounded-l-full last:border-r last:rounded-r-full border-black">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8 border-y border-l first:rounded-l-full last:border-r last:rounded-r-full border-black">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8 border-y border-l first:rounded-l-full last:border-r last:rounded-r-full border-black">hello</button>
    <button class="py-2 px-8 border-y border-l first:rounded-l-full last:border-r last:rounded-r-full border-black">hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, that works, I was trying to use rounded on each button not on parent div and with that it was not possible to use border on parent

Comment: I have encountered new problem.. Im currently using the second solution where each button has all borders except border-r, BUT when I try to use border highlight on button-active it highlights just 3 borders because all buttons except the last one dont have right border

Comment: since border property is already been occupied, you should use `outline` or `ring` class to highlight instead.

Comment: not sure how to use outline/ring, they seem to be based on border, if there is no border-right than there is no outline/ring on the right of the button

I have also tried adding border-r only on hover but that maked 2px border one highlighted and one normal

Comment: [here's some ideas for active btn](https://play.tailwindcss.com/dI7hl8ulK1)

Comment: thank you for helping, I will probably just do border with style on button click